# Move Newsletter Bar - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3

I've tried a few things listed here on the stack but I can't get it to where I want.

I can't even get it to appear in the 'main content' area.

I basically want it from postion 1 to 2 in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in your theme default.xml

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="page.bottom.container" after="-"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between "page.bottom.container" and 'content'? Does this one always keep it at the bottom?

Comment: page.bottom.container always come before footer but within main content.